# Bash script — determine if file modified?

Tags: macos, bash

I have a Bash script that repeatedly copies files every 5 seconds. But this is a touch overkill as usually there is no change.

I know about the Linux command `watch` but as this script will be used on OS X computers (which don’t have `watch`, and I don’t want to make everyone install macports) I need to be able to check if a file is modified or not with straight Bash code.

Should I be checking the file modified time? How can I do that?

*Edit:* I was hoping to expand my script to do more than just copy the file, if it detected a change. So is there a pure-bash way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can use `rsync` instead? It can compare the timestamp and size to the timestamp and size of the target file, and avoid copying if they are the same. (If you're copying to a remote box, there will still be the overhead of connecting, though.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tend to agree with the `rsync` answer if you have big trees of files
to manage, but you can use the -u (--update) flag to cp to copy the
file(s) over only if the source is newer than the destination.

cp -u

**Edit**

Since you've updated the question to indicate that you'd like to take
some additional actions, you'll want to use the `-nt` check
in the `[` (`test`) builtin command:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 -nt $2 ]; then
  echo "File 1 is newer than file 2"
else
  echo "File 1 is older than file 2"
fi
```

From the man page:

```
file1 -nt file2
         True if file1 is newer (according  to  modification  date)  than
         file2, or if file1 exists and file2 does not.
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

OS X has the [`stat`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) command. Something like this should give you the modification time of a file:

```
stat -f '%m' filename
```

The GNU equivalent would be:

```
stat --printf '%Y\n' filename
```

Answer (score 3):

You might find it more reliable to detect changes in the file content by comparing the file size (if the sizes differ, the content does) and the hash of the contents.  It probably doesn't matter much which hash you use for this purpose: SHA1 or even MD5 is probably adequate, and you might find that the `cksum` command is sufficient.

File modification times can change without changing the content (think `touch file`); file modification times can not change even when the content does (doing this is harder, but you could use `touch -r ref-file file` to set the modification times of `file` to match `ref-file` after editing the file).

Comment: Why use a hash instead of bit-for-bit comparison? Isn't bit-for-bit comparison going to be  faster than running through the entire file and forming a hash of it?

Comment: @Pacerier: If the files are different, then byte-by-byte comparison might be quicker unless the last byte is the only one that's different.  If the files are the same, you can only show that by comparing all the bytes.  The advantage of a hash is that you can store the old value of the hash (which is relatively small) and compare it with the new value of the hash regenerated from the current file.  If there's a difference, then the file has changed.  Doing the byte-by-byte comparison requires the old file to be present.

Answer (score 0):

No. You should be using `rsync` or one of its frontends to copy the files, since it will detect if the files are different and only copy them if they are.

Comment: `rsync` is a helpful suggestion (though as you can see in my edit, not quite what I need).  But I find your tone a bit off-putting.

Comment: @Alan H.: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't find the tone off-putting at all. In fact I was surprised by your response.